Why are Average CPU Usage, Average Memory Footprint and Average Load Time marked as N/A in Chrome's discards database?
I read in chrome://discards/database:

Why are Average CPU Usage, Average Memory Footprint and Average Load Time marked as N/A in Chrome's discards database?
I use Chrome on Windows 10.
